# Reading Binary File with PHP

Tags: php, c++, structure

This is the 'C++' Structure used.

```
struct gross
    {
        char date[11];
        char ac[128];
        char type[5];
        float mvalue;
        float netraw;
        float netfer;
        char stat[128];
        float firr;
        float acb;
    };
```

This is the content of binary file generated when compiled with GCC compiler.

> 12/12/1995    d   us  12.23   34.12   90.12   fees    12  56.12
>   01/01/1998    a   us  52.23   54.12   10.12   fees    92  16.12
>   31/12/1999    a   us  52.23   54.12   10.12   fees    92  16.12
>   31/12/1999    d   us  12.23   34.12   90.12   fees    12  56.12
>   01/01/2000    a   us  52.23   54.12   10.12   fees    92  16.12
>   01/01/2000    z   us  12.23   34.12   90.12   fees    12  56.12
>   31/12/2010    a   us  52.23   54.12   10.12   fees    92  16.12
>   31/12/2010    d   us  12.23   34.12   90.12   fees    12  56.12

The PHP coding to read the content of the above binary file.

```
echo "<table>";
while (!feof($f)) {

  if ($s = fread($f, 292)) {

        $nn = unpack('a11date/a128ac/a5type/fmvalue/fnetraw/fnetfer/a128stat/ffirr/facb', $s);

        echo "<td>" . $nn[date] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $nn[ac] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $nn[type] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $nn[mvalue] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $nn[netraw] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $nn[netfer] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $nn[stat] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $nn[firr] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $nn[acb] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
 }
}
        echo "</table>";
fclose($f);
?>
```

This is what I got from the above code. What I'm getting is lot of garbage values in the second and seventh field. And the precision exceeds for the float fields. How to fix this?

> 12/12/1995    d¸³M·g·ew·¤dw·àew·Öúr·ÿÿÿÿ,w·ø;w·Ìª¹¿ô{·{·‹ây·Ð{·SpP·ip·¤dw·ew·€5w·ôOg·
>   X«¹¿»qP·äSg   us  12.229999542236 34.119998931885 90.120002746582 fees·5rP· #Ä äSg· rP·ô›Å #Ä 5rP·0#o·¸xw·x«¹¿·ÅÿÿýŽäSg·¸xw·ÆD¬¹¿L¬¹¿5rP·pòy· 12  56.119998931885
>
> 01/01/1998    a¸³M·g·ew·¤dw·àew·Öúr·ÿÿÿÿ,w·ø;w·Ìª¹¿ô{·{·‹ây·Ð{·SpP·ip·¤dw·ew·€5w·ôOg·
>   X«¹¿»qP·äSg   us  52.229999542236 54.119998931885 10.119999885559 fees·5rP· #Ä äSg· rP·ô›Å #Ä 5rP·0#o·¸xw·x«¹¿·ÅÿÿýŽäSg·¸xw·ÆD¬¹¿L¬¹¿5rP·pòy· 92  16.120000839233
>
> 31/12/1999    a¸³M·g·ew·¤dw·àew·Öúr·ÿÿÿÿ,w·ø;w·Ìª¹¿ô{·{·‹ây·Ð{·SpP·ip·¤dw·ew·€5w·ôOg·
>   X«¹¿»qP·äSg   us  52.229999542236 54.119998931885 10.119999885559 fees·5rP· #Ä äSg· rP·ô›Å #Ä 5rP·0#o·¸xw·x«¹¿·ÅÿÿýŽäSg·¸xw·ÆD¬¹¿L¬¹¿5rP·pòy· 92  16.120000839233
>
> 31/12/1999    d¸³M·g·ew·¤dw·àew·Öúr·ÿÿÿÿ,w·ø;w·Ìª¹¿ô{·{·‹ây·Ð{·SpP·ip·¤dw·ew·€5w·ôOg·
>   X«¹¿»qP·äSg   us  12.229999542236 34.119998931885 90.120002746582 fees·5rP· #Ä äSg· rP·ô›Å #Ä 5rP·0#o·¸xw·x«¹¿·ÅÿÿýŽäSg·¸xw·ÆD¬¹¿L¬¹¿5rP·pòy· 12  56.119998931885
>
> 01/01/2000    a¸³M·g·ew·¤dw·àew·Öúr·ÿÿÿÿ,w·ø;w·Ìª¹¿ô{·{·‹ây·Ð{·SpP·ip·¤dw·ew·€5w·ôOg·
>   X«¹¿»qP·äSg   us  52.229999542236 54.119998931885 10.119999885559 fees·5rP· #Ä äSg· rP·ô›Å #Ä 5rP·0#o·¸xw·x«¹¿·ÅÿÿýŽäSg·¸xw·ÆD¬¹¿L¬¹¿5rP·pòy· 92  16.120000839233
>
> 01/01/2000    z¸³M·g·ew·¤dw·àew·Öúr·ÿÿÿÿ,w·ø;w·Ìª¹¿ô{·{·‹ây·Ð{·SpP·ip·¤dw·ew·€5w·ôOg·
>   X«¹¿»qP·äSg   us  12.229999542236 34.119998931885 90.120002746582 fees·5rP· #Ä äSg· rP·ô›Å #Ä 5rP·0#o·¸xw·x«¹¿·ÅÿÿýŽäSg·¸xw·ÆD¬¹¿L¬¹¿5rP·pòy· 12  56.119998931885
>
> 31/12/2010    a¸³M·g·ew·¤dw·àew·Öúr·ÿÿÿÿ,w·ø;w·Ìª¹¿ô{·{·‹ây·Ð{·SpP·ip·¤dw·ew·€5w·ôOg·
>   X«¹¿»qP·äSg   us  52.229999542236 54.119998931885 10.119999885559 fees·5rP· #Ä äSg· rP·ô›Å #Ä 5rP·0#o·¸xw·x«¹¿·ÅÿÿýŽäSg·¸xw·ÆD¬¹¿L¬¹¿5rP·pòy· 92  16.120000839233
>
> 31/12/2010    d¸³M·g·ew·¤dw·àew·Öúr·ÿÿÿÿ,w·ø;w·Ìª¹¿ô{·{·‹ây·Ð{·SpP·ip·¤dw·ew·€5w·ôOg·
>   X«¹¿»qP·äSg   us  12.229999542236 34.119998931885 90.120002746582 fees·5rP· #Ä äSg· rP·ô›Å #Ä 5rP·0#o·¸xw·x«¹¿·ÅÿÿýŽäSg·¸xw·ÆD¬¹¿L¬¹¿5rP·pòy· 12  56.119998931885

Comment: Its probably the difference in character encodings between the way your compiler outputs that file and the way the php script opens that file. Try to find out what type of encoding that is and if you can open that file in php while specifying how to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP's `pack` and `unpack`, the formatting code `a` stands for NUL *padded* string. In this case it looks like the second and seventh field are not NUL padded; they just have NUL to indicate where the string ends, followed by random data.

To get the part of the string before NUL you can use `substr` and `strpos`:

```
$input = "a\000b"; // string with embedded NUL 
$output = substr($input, 0, strpos($input, "\000"));
var_dump($output); // string(1) "a"
```

---

The float fields have their correct values, the values you see in the output from the C program are rounded. To do the same in PHP you could use `sprintf` for example:

```
$input = 16.120000839233;
$output = sprintf("%.2f", $input);
var_dump($output); // string(5) "16.12"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes because your second argument to unpack is "a128ac" and manual (http://jp2.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) says "a" stands for "NUL-padded string" but you possibly want "A" which is "SPACE-padded string". What you see is garbage because terminator is not found properly.